# Plotting a barplot using ggplot2 doesn´t work

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a barplot using ggplot2, but it shows always the same error.

```
          County      avginc
    1    Los Angelos 116.01993
    2      San Diego  70.04367
    3         Orange  29.15055
    4 San Bernardino  28.32888
    5      Riverside   24.1085
```

```
ggplot(data=a,aes(x=County,y=avginc)) + geom_bar("identity")
```

> Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add `stat = 'identity'` inside `geom_bar()`, otherwise it will assume `mapping = 'identity'`. as an alternative, you can use `geom_col()` without arguments instead of `geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

Comment: Thanks, but now I have the problem, that the y-axis is not labeld correctly. For example the 116.01 showed under 29.15... How can I fix this?

Comment: Based on the plot you put in an answer (which should be an [edit] since it doesn't answer the question), it looks like your y variable is a factor, not a numeric vector. This is why having a sample of your data _in its actual format_, not just a printout of it, is helpful.

Comment: @R.K. you need to convert `avginc` (that is a character column in your case) into a numeric one: `a$avginc <- as.numeric(a$avginc`

Answer (score 0):

Now it worked to plot it, but the output is still not satisfying.
The y-axis is not labeled in the correct order.

```
 ggplot(data=a,aes(x=County,y=avginc))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AI2X.png)

Comment: this is a weird plot. Can you give the code you used to produce your dataframe `a` ?

Comment: Most likely the data in the "avginc" is character or factor type and not numeric.  Run `str(a)` to understand the column types.

Answer (score 0):

Use `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar()`.

you can reorder the categorical `x` variable using `forcats::fct_reorder()`.
(the package `forcats` is included when loading `tidyverse`).

```
library(tidyverse)
a <- data.frame(County = c("Los Angeles", "San Diego", "Orange", "San Bernardino", "Riverside"),
                avginc = c(116.019, 70.04, 29.15, 28.32, 24.1))

ggplot(data = a, aes(x = fct_reorder(County, -avginc), y = avginc)) +
  geom_col()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same code, but you have a different output.

```
a <- tribble(
~County,~avginc,
"Los Angelos", 116.01993,
"San Diego" , 70.04367,
"Orange" , 29.15055,
"San Bernardino" , 28.32888,
"Riverside" , 24.1085
)


ggplot(data=a,aes(x=County,y=avginc)) +
geom_bar(stat ="identity")
```

[image]